# Element.scrollIntoView not working outside of a timeout in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, js-scrollintoview

I have a really strange problem using scrollIntoView. In and Safari and Chrome the code works when I open a new window or tab, but does not work when I push the `Refresh` button. In Firefox it always works. When I use a `setTimeout()` the `Refresh` button triggers a scrolling in all browsers like this:

```
setTimeout( function () {scrollToSelection();}, 1);
```

```js
scrollToSelection = function() {
  var element = document.querySelector('p');
  element.scrollIntoView();
};
```

```css
p {
  margin-top: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body onload="scrollToSelection()">
  <p>Some text to see
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: In my case, even firefox isn't working properly either